Integral of $\int_{\Re\lambda=\gamma_0} \frac{e^{\lambda t}}{\lambda^2+c^2}d\lambda$ where $\gamma_0>0$ and $c>0$.
I want to deform the contour to the imaginary axis but avoiding the poles $\lambda=\pm ic$. To avoid the poles one can use half-circles $C_\pm=\{\lambda\in\mathbb C:\lambda = \pm ic+\epsilon e^{i\theta},-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\}$ with centre $\pm i c$ and of radius $\epsilon$. First I write $$\frac{1}{\lambda^2+c^2}=\frac{1}{2ic}\Big(\frac{1}{\lambda-ic}-\frac{1}{\lambda+ic}\Big).$$ This yields, for $C_+$, $$\int_{C_+}\frac{1}{\lambda^2+c^2}\,d\lambda=\frac{\epsilon}{2c}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{i\theta}e^{(ic+\epsilon e^{i\theta})t}\Big(\frac{1}{(ic+\epsilon e^{i\theta})-ic}-\frac{1}{(ic+\epsilon e^{i\theta})+ic}\Big)\,d\theta$$
but I'm not too sure how to proceed.
Is this the best way to compute$$\int_{\Re\lambda=\gamma_0} \frac{e^{\lambda t}}{\lambda^2+c^2}\,d\lambda$$ or is there an easier way?

Your integral is $2\pi i$-times the inverse Laplace transform  of $\frac{1}{\lambda^2+c^2}$, which is $t\mapsto\frac{\sin ct}{c}$.
To calculate this explicitely, it suffices to use just one semicircle:
For $T>0$, let $\alpha_T$ be the straight line parallel to the imaginary axis from $\gamma_0-iT$ to $\gamma_0+iT$, and $\beta_T$ the half-circle from $\gamma_0+iT$ to $\gamma_0-iT$ which encircles the two poles $\pm ci$ on the imaginary axis for sufficiently large $T>0$.
By the residue theorem, this means that for sufficiently large $T>0$ and $f(\lambda ):= \frac{e^{\lambda t}}{\lambda^2+c^2}$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int\limits_{\alpha_T} f(\lambda)d\lambda + \int\limits_{\beta_T} f(\lambda)d\lambda\right) &=    \operatorname{Res}(f,\lambda = ic) + 2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f,\lambda = -ic) \\
 &= \frac{e^{ict}}{2ic}+ \frac{e^{-ict}}{-2ic}\\
  &= \frac{\sin(ct)}{c}\end{align}
On the other hand, for $T\rightarrow\infty$, the integral over $\alpha_T$ tends to the integral you are interested in, while the integral over $\beta_T$ tends to zero by standard arguments.
